# Floating comments/ chat section

Tags: flask, web, comments

Hey guys this is my first question here.

I’m envisioning having a floating(picture in picture) chat/ comments section. Where users can interact with each other, but it will be able to move freely on a computer screen independent of the website. I’m trying to get some guidance on whether something like this exits or if it’s possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a simple chat application that have minimize window.
https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-widget-python

Comment: Ericsson thank you so much, this is pretty much what I was looking for, I had no idea anyone would respond. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ericsson this method enables a private connection between the user and an admin, do you know of a way to make this a public one, where anyone can put there input in and it can act like a comments section?

Comment: This is a discussion app https://opensource.com/article/18/4/flask